# useAutomationExtension in karate testing framework

Tags: karate

Is it possible to set the useAutomationExtension to false in karate chromedriver? Since chrome is complaining that it is unable to load the extensions as it is disabled by the admin. If not any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should just use the Docker container: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Docker